# Does OpenStack Horizons expose iops numbers for instances and volumes?

Tags: terraform, openstack

OpenStack has the ability to set iops quotas with Teraform using [`openstack_blockstorage_qos_v3`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs/resources/blockstorage_qos_v3) which seems to correspond to [Block Storage API 3](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/block-storage/v3/) in OpenStack.

My question is on setting the `qos_specs`

```yaml
specs = {
  read_iops_sec  = "40000"
  write_iops_sec = "40000"
}
```

Can I use Horizons (the web interface) to find peak `iops` for a running  instance? If not, is this metric recorded somewhere that I can get with the API? I'd like to find his information out for a volume, and and an instance (with all the volumes backing it).

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the provider of the underlying Openstack infrastructure.

You will need Monasca, Ceilometer to gather the data for you.

https://www.openstack.org/software/project-navigator/openstack-components#operations-tooling